# Log4j PatternLayout - Prepend value to %c

Tags: java, log4j, pattern-layout

My current Conversion Pattern within my log4j.xml file is as follows:

```
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d (%F:%L) %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
```

I have a simple requirement to prepend %c (which is 'ERROR') with the word 'Runtime'. Using the pattern layout is there anyway I can simply add this word into the pattern for it to print out to the log file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `%d (%F:%L) %-5p Runtime%c - %m%n` ?

Comment: Thanks Jackopo, feel free to add this as a legit answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the string to the pattern:

`%d (%F:%L) %-5p Runtime%c - %m%n`